# Condensation and air leak from skylight

Tags: caulking, condensation, skylight

I Recently started seeing condensation on my skylight. Skylight is installed in the bathroom. Sometime on windy day I feel air coming through skylight. If I raise my hand up towards it I can feel little air.

My questionS are
 1. Can I Caulk the skylight from inside or I have to get on to roof to caulk?
 2. Will caulking solve condensation and air coming into to bathroom?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Firstly you have to find out where the leak is happening. Then you decide how to fix it. We can't possibly answer your question about caulk until you do. Are you even sure there's a leak? Skylights are common locations for condensation of interior moisture. That alone doesn't indicate failure.

Comment: @isherwood  he does say he feels a draft, tho' that remains to be confirmed (as opposed to just feeling cold air).  I agree that  inspection from the outside is mandatory.